# Change parameter used in datatables ajax url.Action on Ajax.reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I was wandering if its possible to pass in a different parameter to a controller using Ajax.reload() in datatables.

thanks to another topic on stackoverflow, I was able to pass in parameter from my variable in to url.Action on creating the table `new { cyfy = "_Switch" })".replace("_Switch",Switch)`

Then on button click i change the state of the variable ( to 0 or 1 ) and call Ajax.reload() on my table.

The issues is that controller receives the same parameter value on each reload.  It seems that this part is not run with the reload:

```
 "ajax": {
           "url": "@Url.Action("GetProjects", "mytool",new { cyfy = "_Switch" })".replace("_Switch",Switch),
            "type": "get",
            "datatype": "json"
         },
```

I was wandering if there is a way to pass in different parameter value on datatables ajax.realod ?

Below bigger part of the code:

```
                     $("#toggle").change(function () {


                     if ($('#toggle').is(':checked') == true) {

                         Switch = 1
                     }
                     else {
                         Switch = 0
                     }
/////////////////

          var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
                             "bPaginate": false,
                              dom: 'Bifrtp',
                             "ajax": {
                                 "url": "@Url.Action("GetProjects", "mytool",new { cyfy = "_Switch" })".replace("_Switch",Switch),
                                 "type": "get",
                                 "datatype": "json"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
The issue was that Ajax was adding timestamp to the request on the reload.

to solve this I have added `cache : true,` option while creating a table.

and then I am reloading the table using ajax.url

```
 var testURL = CreateUrl("mytool/GetProjects?cyfy=") + Switch;
 $('#myDatatable').DataTable().ajax.url(testURL).load();
```